# Classes inheritance

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, instanceof

I have two classes:

```
class ItemInfo {

   public View createItemView() {
       View v;
       // ...
       v.setTag(this); 
       return v;
   }
}

class FolderInfo extends ItemInfo {

    @Override
    public View createItemView() {
        View v;
        // ...
        v.setTag(this);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then I use it:

```
FolderInfo folderInfo;
// Create it here
ItemInfo itemInfo = folderInfo;
View v = itemInfo.createItemView();
Object objectTag = v.getTag();
```

Then I check type of objectTag by instanceof, and it's ItemInfo! Why?

Comment: What variable are you checking the type of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do this:

```
if (itemInfo instanceof ItemInfo) {
    System.out.println("OK!");
}
```

You'll ofcourse see `"OK!"` being printed, because `FolderInfo` is a subclass of `ItemInfo` - so a `FolderInfo` is also an `ItemInfo` object.

Inheritance means that there is an "is a" relationship from the subclass to the superclass - see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 1):

You can check by typing:

```
if (iteminfo instanceof FolderInfo) {
// do what you want
}
else if (iteminfo instanceof ItemInfo) {
// do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`InstanceOf` is a check  for `IS A` relationship.

if(`ChildClass instanceOd ParentClass`) always returns you `true`. even all classes implement interface `A` will pass the test of `(AllClassess instanceOf A)`

In your case **FolderInfo** is a **ItemInfo**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Enumeration` defining all the types .

**Here is how the above code will look like:**

```
class View {
    public ItemInfo getTag() {
       return tag;
    }
}

enum ItemType {
    FolderType,
    FileType
};


class ItemInfo {
  private abstract ItemType getType();

 public View createItemView() {
   View v;
   // ...
   v.setTag(this); 
   return v;
  }
}

class FolderInfo extends ItemInfo {

private  ItemType getType() {
  return ItemType.FolderType;
}
@Override
public View createItemView() {
    View v;
    // ...
    v.setTag(this);
    return v;
  }
}
```

**Which will allow you write better and neat code like this** :

```
switch(itemType) {
      case ItemType.FolderType:
          //handle folder type
          break;
      case ItemType.FileType:
          //handle folder type
          break;
}
```

And wherever you want to check the type you can check like this:

```
  if( itemInfo.getType() == ItemType.FolderType) {
  }
```